# Pass installation path to installer

Tags: command-line, installation

Which Setup builder can create a Setup.exe that accepts installation path in command line parameters?

I need to create an installer that run silently and accept installation path in command line parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something easier to learn you can try [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html), it comes with a free edition that can create "Simple" project type, with an MSI as output, to which the above command line can be applied. Its GUI based, so you don't need to script the projects, but it supports command line builds too.

**EDIT**

Advanced Installer uses APPDIR property to store/set the installation path for an MSI, so you need this command line:

> msiexec /i setup.msi /qn APPDIR="C:\Program Files\My Company\My App"

Make sure you run this from an elevated, cmd.exe launched with "Run as admin" option, command line if you install the package per-machine, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: How use command lines to run msi silently and set installation path?

Comment: Is it possible to cancel the installation process when I need?

Comment: Yes, when running with full/basic UI. Rollback is performed to leave the machine as it was before you started the installation.

Comment: in quite mode you can cancel the install only if you kill the process, as you have no UI. So you will not have rollback, this is valid for any MSI package, doesn't matter what tool is used to build it.

Answer (score 0):

The windows MSI format has this capability. You can pass in parameters on the command line via `msiexec`.

```
msiexec /i installer.msi /qn PARAMETER=foo
```

One of those parameters will be the installation path.

You can build an MSI using the free [WiX toolkit](http://wixtoolset.org/). WiX is really powerful, but due to it being XML driven, it does have a bit of a steep learning curve (maybe a couple of days before you are fairly competent). If you have access to Visual Studio then that will help a lot.

Comment: But I first tried to wrap an msi in my application in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311196/make-an-installer-with-delphi) link and the users says that msi is not good!!!

Comment: If you want to make a windows installer then an MSI is definitely the correct choice. It does both things you need and there is a very good toolkit for building them (WiX is actually what the Office installer is built from). Why don't you try it and see if it suits your needs.